# How in angular 2 put [attr.ref] dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

Example:

```
 <app-component *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" [attr.ref]="i">
 </app-component>
```

How put

```
<app #idModal></app>
```

where **idModal** is dynamic and not name static.

Comment: You can't add template variables (like `#idModal`) dynamically. The only way is to add them statically in the components template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function do to this

```
<app-component *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" [attr.ref]="concatenate(i)">
 </app-component>

concatenate(i){
    return '#' + i;
}
```

If you want to have `#idModal` just modify your function as

```
concatenate(i){
        return '#' + i+ 'Modal';
    }
```

Comment: I have this problem <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index"><modal #idModal></modal><button (click)="idModal.open()"/></div> it open all modal or enter in every modal not assign a diferent ref to every modal?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?